# Can jackson deserialize from different JSON string to same object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a JSON string, like this:

```
{
...
"token": "abc123"
...
}
```

Then for some reason, have to update to a new structure, the expected incoming JSON string becomes:

```
{
...
"token": {"property01":"true", "property02":"false", "value": "abc123"}
...
}
```

Originally, the token field was in string type, now, it becomes an object, with additional properties.

I need to handle both format for backward compatibility, can jackson handle this case?

Comment: You can probably do that with a custom `JsonDeserializer`.

Comment: yes, just trying to find an sample code of JsonDeserializer for my case ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating your own deserializer:

```
class FooJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        //deserialize your data here
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add the deserializer to your class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = FooJsonDeserializer.class)
class Foo {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would really like to know why I get a minus for my answer. It would be heplful to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: This doesn't deserve a down vote.  Up-voting to counteract it.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate `token` setter with `@JsonDeserialize(using=YourCustomDeserializer.class)` and provide logic only for one field deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Jackson module I wrote for handling versioning. See the examples on the README for info on how to use it.

https://github.com/jonpeterson/jackson-module-model-versioning